# Disable paste menu iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, paste

My app currently uses the following code to prevent the user utilising the paste menu but unfortunately `setMenuVisible:NO` has been deprecated from iOS 13.

```
//Disable Paste Menu
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
    }];
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Xcode informs me that `hideMenuFromView` is the replacement to `setMenuVisible`...can anyone offer an equivalent code snippet successfully disabling the paste menu in a similar manner using `hideMenuFromView` please?

Comment: simply return `false` in your `canPerformAction`

Answer (score 0):

Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller/3044216-hidemenufromview?language=objc for changes to implementation. Specifically this new hide menu function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller/3044215-hidemenu?language=objc